# 4 and 6 additions only

Tags: combinations

Given a number **n**, In how many ways ,  **n** can be formed by adding 4 and 6 only with atmost **m** times use of 6 and 4.
For example :
12 in two ways with atmost three times (4 or 6)
{4,4,4}
{6,6}

**Second example:**

10 in only one way 
{4,6}

Comment: Rather easy if $n$ is odd or equal to $2$ or greater than $6m$

Comment: It's worth mentioning whether or not the order matters (especially since the example isn't obvious about it).

Comment: order doesn't matter